# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ProvideMetadataToAnnotationScanTask.initializeIvars after adding Weld

Tags: jsf, tomcat, mojarra, weld

I am trying to use OmniFaces for converters. However it will not initialize. I am running eclipse on Ubuntu. I have not implemented any converters or any other OmniFaces code in the project yet. But the intention is to use list converters and possibly other converters with PrimeFaces.

This problem does not seem to be related to omnifaces however. It seems like it could be depending on multiple versions of JSF. However I only have mojarra in my project. Could it be any of the other dependencies that conflicts. The problem did not arrise until I tried to include omnifaces. Primefaces has been running without a problem.

stacktrace

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:453)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:516)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.processAnnotations(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:446)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:359)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:512)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ProvideMetadataToAnnotationScanTask.initializeIvars(ConfigManager.java:877)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ProvideMetadataToAnnotationScanTask.getAnnotationScanURIs(ConfigManager.java:890)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ProvideMetadataToAnnotationScanTask.access$400(ConfigManager.java:834)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:962)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:916)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:387)
    ... 10 more

<!-- o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{backingLeague.listLeague.source}" /  -->
```

Dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
        <version>5.2</version>  
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Page include

```
<h:html lang="sv-SE" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
```

context.xml

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="BeanManager" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

Comment: So, when you remove only OmniFaces from the dependencies (and keep Weld), this problem disappears?

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce it on Tomcat 8.0.26 based on the information provided so far (and an empty beans.xml). Neither with Mojarra 2.2.11 nor with current 2.2.12.

Comment: I found this Mojarra issue report: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3880 Seems to be Mojarra+Weld+Tomcat specific. So when you removed OmniFaces for test, you apparently also removed Weld. Try latest Mojarra and latest Tomcat.

Comment: Will do! However seems hardly worth it since I will only use it for converters. Probably faster to just write my own custom .